# Find child by ID from collection of parent laravel

Tags: laravel

I have Parent - Child relationship

**Parent Model**

```
public function child() {
     return $this->hasMany(Child::class);
}
```

**Child Model**

```
public function parent() {
     return $this->belongsTo(Parent::class);
}
```

**App**

I am getting the parent collection which I am using elsewhere

```
$this->parent = Parent::where('active', true)->with('child')->get()
```

**The Problem**

I have a on-click function where i'm getting just the ID of the child. So i'm trying to find the child in the parent collection.

```
public function click($id) {
     $child = $this->parent->child()->find('id', $id)->first();
}
```

Error -

> Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::child does not exist.

Is it possible to get the child from the existing collection, I know I could do another db query but really not wanting to make another query as I already have the data just there.

**$this->parent->toArray()**

```
array:2 [▼
0 => array:11 [▼
"id" => 1
"active" => 1
"name" => "Foo"
"child" => array:3 [▼
  0 => array:3 [▼
    "id" => 1
    "parent_id" => 1
    "name" => "S/M"
  ]
  1 => array:3 [▼
    "id" => 2
    "parent_id" => 1
    "name" => "L/XL"
  ]
  2 => array:3 [▼
    "id" => 3
    "parent_id" => 1
    "name" => "2XL"
  ]
]
```

]

Answer (score 2):

You can use `where condition` to find using child id

```
$this->parent->where('child.id', $id)->first()
```

if you are looking to find parent id then

```
 $this->parent->find($id)
```

you have hasmany data so

```
 $this->parent->filter(function ($value)use($id){
           return $value->child->find($id);
        })->first();
```

Comment: That is returning null

Comment: can you show what output you have in dd($this->parent->toArray());

Comment: @TonySawlwin see child is empty so it returing null if you are find using parent then it should be $this->parent->where('id', $id)->first()

Comment: Sorry I clicked enter to early (now edited) but child has 3

Comment: @TonySawlwin then it should work .can you add to question what you have in dd($this->parent->toArray());

Comment: Just added to question, Thanks

Comment: @TonySawlwin updted answer

Comment: Thank you, The $this->parent->filter option works, but It is returning the parent with all its children. For what I'm trying todo, that is actually all I needed is the parent. But if you did want just the child then would have to for loop through the children or something.

Comment: @TonySawlwin.even you can query instead because even collection also iterate over all .so it doesn't male much difference as per my  understanding